# Populating pandas column based on moving date range (efficiently)

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I have 2 `pandas` dataframes, one of them contains dates with measurements, and the other contains dates with an event ID.

**df1**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today = dt.now()
ndays = 10

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [today + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(ndays)], 'measurement': pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, high = 10, size = ndays))})
df1.Date = df1.Date.dt.date


   Date    measurement
2018-01-10     8
2018-01-11     2
2018-01-12     7
2018-01-13     3
2018-01-14     1
2018-01-15     1
2018-01-16     6
2018-01-17     9
2018-01-18     8
2018-01-19     4
```

**df2**

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-11', '2018-01-14', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-19'], 'letter': ['event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c', 'event_d']})
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df2.Date = df2.Date.dt.date

   Date     event_id
2018-01-11  event_a
2018-01-14  event_b
2018-01-16  event_c
2018-01-19  event_d
```

I give the dates in `df1` an `event_id` from `df2` only if it's between two event dates. The resulting dataframe would look something like:

**df3**

```
today = dt.now()
ndays = 10

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [today + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(ndays)], 'measurement': pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, high = 10, size = ndays)), 'event_id': ['event_a', 'event_a', 'event_b', 'event_b', 'event_b', 'event_c', 'event_c', 'event_d', 'event_d', 'event_d']})
df3.Date = df3.Date.dt.date



  Date      event_id  measurement
2018-01-10  event_a       4
2018-01-11  event_a       2
2018-01-12  event_b       1
2018-01-13  event_b       5
2018-01-14  event_b       5
2018-01-15  event_c       4
2018-01-16  event_c       6
2018-01-17  event_d       6
2018-01-18  event_d       9
2018-01-19  event_d       6
```

The code I use to achieve this is:

```
n = 1
while n <= len(list(df2.Date)) - 1 :
    for date in list(df1.Date):
        if date <= df2.iloc[n].Date and (date > df2.iloc[n-1].Date):
            df1.loc[df1.Date == date, 'event_id'] = df2.iloc[n].event_id

    n += 1
```

The dataset that I am working with is significantly larger than this (a few million rows) and this method runs far too long. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

So there are quite a few things to improve performance.
The first question I have is: does it have to be a pandas frame to begin with? Meaning can't df1 and df2 just be lists of tuples or list of lists?

The thing is that pandas adds a significant overhead when accessing items but especially when setting values individually. 
Pandas excels when it comes to vectorized operations but I don't see an efficient alternative right now (maybe someone comes up with such an answer, that would be ideal).

Now what I'd do is:

1. Convert your df1 and df2 to records -> e.g. `d1 = df1.to_records()` what you get is an array of tuples, basically with the same structure as the dataframe.
2. Now run your algorithm but instead of operating on pandas dataframes you operate on the arrays of tuples `d1` and `d2`
3. Use a third list of tuples `d3` where you store the newly created data (each tuple is a row)

Now if you want you can convert d3 back to a pandas dataframe:

`df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d3, myKwArgs**)`

This will speed up your code significantly I'd assume by more than 100-1000%. It does increase memory usage though, so if you are low on memory try to avoid the pandas dataframes all-together or dereference unused pandas frames `df1, df2` once you used them to create the records (and if you run into problems call gc manually).

EDIT: Here a version of your code using the procedure above:

```
d3 = []
n = 1
while n < range(len(d2)):
    for i in range(len(d1)):
        date = d1[i][0]
        if date <= d2[n][0] and date > d2[n-1][0]:
            d3.append( (date, d2[n][1], d1[i][1]) )
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try df.apply() method to achieve this. Refer [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). I think my code will works faster than yours.

**My approach:**

- Merge two dataframes df1 and df2 and create new one df3 by

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='outer')
```

- Sort df3 by date to make easy to travserse.

```
df3['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3.Date)
df3.sort_values(by='Date')
```

- Create set_event_date() method to apply for each rows in df3.

```
new_event_id = np.nan 
def set_event_date(df3):
    global new_event_id
    if df3.event_id is not np.nan:
       new_event_id = df3.event_id
    return new_event_id
```

- Apply set_event_method() to each rows in df3.

```
df3['new_event_id'] = df3.apply(set_event_date,axis=1)
```

**Final Output will be:**

```
Date Measurement New_event_id
0   2018-01-11  2   event_a
1   2018-01-12  1   event_a
2   2018-01-13  3   event_a
3   2018-01-14  6   event_b
4   2018-01-15  3   event_b
5   2018-01-16  5   event_c
6   2018-01-17  7   event_c
7   2018-01-18  9   event_c
8   2018-01-19  7   event_d
9   2018-01-20  4   event_d
```

Let me know once you tried my solution and it works faster than yours.
Thanks.